# WPF TextBlock Overlaps Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create this in WPF (I realize I could just use an image, but I am trying to learn WPF):

[image]

([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20130628020452/http://www.iconarchive.com/show/ios7-icons-by-visualpharm/info-icon.html))

This is what I have so far but it isn't producing the desired result, in that, the textbox seems completely hide the ellipse whereas it should simply have a transparent background:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,207,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="142,189,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can put things like this in a viewbox to make scaling easier, something like this. You'll need to remove the stack panel, it's going to stack items one on top of the other which isn't what you're after here. I used a grid in this case.

```
<Viewbox Width="100" Height="100">
    <Grid Width="20" Height="20">
        <Ellipse Stroke="Black"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="i" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 10):

Or you can use the unicode character:  **ⓘ**

code 0x24D8

```
 <TextBlock Text="ⓘ" FontSize="52" />
```

Comment: This in an interesting answer.  Will this work on all machines are is this a particular font or something that I should be concerned with?

Comment: It is standard Unicode and ought to work on all machines (that can run WPF), but you'll have to test when using special fonts.

Comment: This is not related to what he's asking, he wants to learn WPF (I take it he's trying to figure out controls and layouts), using a char will not help him accomplish that.

Comment: Yes, I was specifically trying to rebuild it so as to learn WPF controls and layouts; however, this is still an interesting, minimal, and probably better solution!

Comment: A single char TextBlock is WPF too...  And this has one big advantage: no need to specify (and match) Height and Width. You can add a Margin but the FontSize acts as SPOD.

Answer (score 5):

So a stackpanel will place the first item at the top, the second just below it, third below the second, and so forth. What you could do is use a Canvas or a Grid. Like the stackpanel, they are "Content Controls" and support placing multiple objects inside of them like you have done with the stackpanel.

So a really quick way to do what you're trying to accomplish would be:

```
<Grid >
        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52"  Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52"/>
        <TextBlock  Text="i" FontSize="52" Margin="18,-13,-6,13" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using a border and a TextBlock. A square border will become a circle if you make its CornerRadius equals half its Width (or Height):

```xml
        <Border Width="100" Height="100"  CornerRadius="50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 FontSize="50"   Foreground="Blue"  >i</TextBlock>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a StackPanel for this, the purpose of it is to stack things, not show them overlapped, you're using the wrong tool for that. Use a Grid, it's far more suited for what you're trying to do.

To have a transparent background, you have to either set the TextBlock's [Background property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.background.aspx) to Transparent, or set a null background.

```
Background={x:Null}
```