# How to Fill SolidColorBrush/Ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="48" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.014,0.003" Margin="0,0,104,5">               
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#683FB0"></SolidColorBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>  
</Ellipse>
```

Inside that colored circle, I want to add an `icon`/`textblock` etc.

Comment: Besides that you could have written `<Ellipse ... Fill="#683FB0"/>`, just add the Ellipse and whatever you want to put on top of it to a common Panel, e.g. a Grid.

Comment: You may want to have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970797/wpf-textblock-overlaps-ellipse/17970954)